# can the algorithm cost be negative?

Tags: algorithm, search, a-star, search-tree

I was reading an article and I've found the graph below that represents the algorithm cost, and I was wondering if the values are representing the algorithm cost why they are negative? and what are they referring to ? I also would like to know the algorithm cost is calculated according to what and why the each value has a sort of a min and max value ?
Thank you.

Update:
here is the link for the paper: [Real-Time Planning as Decision-Making under Uncertainty](https://ojs.aaai.org/index.php/AAAI/article/view/4073#:%7E:text=In%20real%2Dtime%20planning%2C%20an,with%20the%20lowest%20f%20value.)

[image]

Comment: Based on the graph it looks like "cost" refers to some relative cost, with respect to "Cserna" which is used as a baseline. To know exactly what they mean by "positive" or "negative" cost, you'd need to link the article...

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I updated the post, but I did not understand when you said that they are referring to some relative cost, could you please explain more to me ?

Comment: The graph's Y label reads "Algorithm cost – Cserna cost", which would seem to indicate that the value being graphed is the difference between each algorithm's cost and the cost of the Cserna algorithm. That's verified by observing that the Cserna algorithm's Y value is always 0. The graph's title says that it measures 15 puzzles; presumably they don't all give the same results, which is why a range of values is shown.

Comment: @rici aa okay now I understand thank you so much.